# How to fix an array element with a sequence?

Tags: vectorization, sequence, word2vec, training-data, valueerror

Got this issue, and I do not know how to fix it?

```
ValueError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 2
      1 # Generate aggregated sentence vectors based on the word vectors for each word in the sentence
----> 2 w2v_vect = np.array([np.array([w2v_model.wv[i] for i in ls if i in w2v_model.wv.index_to_key])
      3                      for ls in X_test])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (1115,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I do not know what and how to modify.

Comment: What's the full code that triggered the error, and what task is it trying to achieve? Was it copied from someplace that gave you reason to think it would work? Is that the full error/traceback? (You can edit extra details into your question, where the space/formatting will make it more understandable – and  should show at the very least the cell-8 code that seems to have triggered the error, but ideally also any earlier code clarifying what variables have been set up as well. )

Comment: I APPRECIATE YOU! This has been resolved. This was a guided exercise activity from the LinkedIn course, and due to multiple updates to installations, there are way too many deprecated commands and new errors popping up.

Comment: Please create an answer post, so that your gained insight can benefit others.